# Crystal Reports SQL query give strange results - can someone explain why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, date, crystal-reports

I'm updating some old crystal reports in the company when I by accident found that some are searching for date in a `yyyy-MM-dd` range and others in a `yyyyMMdd` range. I also found that they result in a slightly different result, so I started to investigate this further.

I checked the database (running on MS SQL Server) and it stores date as a string in `yyyyMMdd` format in the field that is being searched.

In the reports that uses the `yyyy-MM-dd` format the SQL query made by Crystal Reports contains

```
WHERE ("Remiss_ank"."Skapad_datum">='2013-07-01' 
  AND "Remiss_ank"."Skapad_datum"<='2013-07-31')
```

whereas the reports that uses the `yyyyMMdd` format has a SQL query containing

```
WHERE ("Remiss_ank"."Skapad_datum">='20130701' 
  AND "Remiss_ank"."Skapad_datum"<='20130731')
```

As all dates in the database are stored in the `yyyyMMdd` format I would understand if the former would not give any results at all, but it actually returns a subset of the latter. In fact the first query returns all records with dates in the range 20130702 to 20130731.

Can someone explain why I see this result, and why the string `2013-07-02` is considered to part of the string interval `20130701` to `20130731` whereas `2013-07-01` is not.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're storing the dates as strings. Don't do that. There are date and datetime data types for a reason.

Try this to see

```
if ('20130701'>='2013-07-01') select '1'
if ('20130702'>='2013-07-01') select '2'
```

If you insist, try changing your collation

```
if ('20130701'>='2013-07-01' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI ) select '1a'
if ('20130701'>='2013-07-01' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ) select '1b'
```

Comment: I'm fully aware of the `date` and `datetime` data types, and that dates shouldn't be stored as strings. Unfortunately, the company that delivers out LIS software seems not to be, and I have to live with that.
I'll check the code you suggested next week when I get back to work.
I still don't get why any collation would say that `20130701 < 2013-07-01 < 20130702 < 2013-07-02`